# select case when number then char in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query that in case detect a number and in then shows me a char but not works. My sentence is:

```sql
SELECT xxxx 
CASE
    WHEN status=11 THEN 'OK' 
    WHEN status=33 THEN 'BAD' 
    ELSE status 
END,
...............
```

It gives me an error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "OK"

What's wrong? Any help, please?
Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: Missing comma between `xxxx` and the `case` expression.

Comment: as status seems to be integer: else status::varchar

Comment: Please start any such question with a table definition. The data type of the column is essential. Also: what data type should the result be? Just `text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert to a string.  Something like this:

```
(case when status = 11 then 'OK'
      when status = 33 then 'BAD'
      else status::text
 end),
```

A `case` expression returns a single value, with a specified type.  By the rules of SQL, when you mix strings and numbers, *numbers* are preferred.

Postgres makes it easy to convert the value you want to a string in the `else` clause.